# Question about a matrix identity

Tags: matrices

I am now looking at a proof that uses a matrix identity
$\ln (\det M) = tr(\ln M)$
I am not sure what does $\ln M$ mean here, can any body help me?

Comment: Do you know what the matrix exponential is? That is, do you know what $e^M$ means?

Comment: Matrix logarithms [are defined here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

The matrix logarithm is a quite complicated thing. The matrix  exponential is simpler: For a square matrix $A$ set
$$
e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}
$$
(and the series always converges). A matrix logarithm of $M$ is any matrix $A$ that fulfills $e^A = M$. So substitute $M=e^A$, then $\ln M = A$ and now plug your identity into the exponential function (the usual one for real/complex numbers) and get
$$
\det(e^A) = e^{\operatorname{tr} A}
$$
which may be more familiar. You can find proofs of this equality on book on ODEs in the chapters on solutions on linear systems of ODEs.